# how To get list File And Folder selected in Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I need to get the path of the currently selected File or Folder in Windows Explorer to put the `ListView`. I do not know how to do hope you can help.Thank you

Update Source

```
public void GetListFileAndFolderOfWindowsExploer()
{
    try
    {
        string fileName;

        ArrayList selected = new ArrayList();
        Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();

        foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer windows in new SHDocVw.ShellWindows())
        {
            fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(windows.FullName).ToLower();

            if (fileName.ToLowerInvariant() == "explorer")
            {
                Shell32.FolderItems items = ((Shell32.IShellFolderViewDual2)windows.Document).SelectedItems();

                foreach (Shell32.FolderItem item in items)
                {
                    lift = new string[] { item.Name, item.Path };

                    ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem();
                    list.Text = item.Name;
                    list.SubItems.Add(item.Path);
                    list.UseItemStyleForSubItems = true;
                    listView1.Items.Add(list);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        writelog(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you select your file?

Comment: more details pls, what are you trying to accomplish? there can be more than one windows explorer windows open at a time or none.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To in order to get selected items you have to use the following interfaces:

```
IServiceProvider
IShellBrowser
IFolderView
IShellFolder2
IPersistFolder2
```

or directly

```
(IEnumIDList and LPITEMIDLIST) foreach all selected items
```

This works fine in Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `OpenFileDialog`([Home and learn OpenFileDialog](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s4p9.html)).

Hope this link helps.

```
OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
fdlg.Title = "C# Help";
fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     string dirName =
     System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fdlg.FileName);
     string drive =
     dirName.Split(System.IO.Path.VolumeSeparatorChar)[0];
     MessageBox.Show(dirName);
     MessageBox.Show(drive);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems unclear,Hope you are using `OpenFileDialog` for selecting files,

If you're looking for the file path:

```
string path = OpenFileDialog1.FileName; //output = c:\folder\file.txt
```

If you're looking for the directory path:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName); //output = c:\folder
```

In general, the `System.IO.Path` class has a lot of useful features for retrieving and manipulating path information.

Comment: Do I write 1 program nho.va take into Context Menu.when I R-click the file or folder, the program will be run and it will take the path of the folder or file.